# QTreeView multiple issues (row hover highlights, child row highlights, row selection with multiple columns)

Tags: qt, hover, highlight, pyqt5, qtreeview

### Versions

- pyqt5
- python 3.6

---

### Setup

I'm having a few issues with the `QTreeView` class.

The `QTreeView` is configured as:

```
treeView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
```

There are **no custom style sheets** on this `QTreeView`

I've implemented a custom model for the view, and the `flags()` definition is:

```
def flags(self, index):
    if not index.isValid():
        return 0

    f = super(RecordTreeModel, self).flags(index)

    f = f | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled

    return f
```

Is there anything else relevant to the situation? I'm not doing anything fancy with my model. No custom painting, no special selection requirements -- everything is straight out of basic model examples besides the way the data structure is accessed.

---

## Issues

#### Row Selection

When clicking on any column besides the first column, the row will **not be selected.**

#### Column Hovering

When hovering over any column besides the first column, the row will **not be highlighted**

#### Child Hovering

No child rows are ever highlighted when the mouse hovers over them.

---

I've been banging my head (and google's search bar) against these problems for several hours, to no avail.

*Please let me know if I can provide any additional information!*

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro I'll try to work out a minimal example.